# twist correction of fan blades

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, engine, turbojet

How can the blade's angle be effectively adjusted to meet prescribed tolerances during shop repairs?

I am conducting a research paper on aircraft engine blade maintenance, and I have encountered limited information on the repair methods and techniques used to correct the twist angle.

Comment: Maybe because there isn't a need to "correct" the twist angle?  Most blades are blended to remove knicks, and if damage is beyond a certain point they are simply replaced.  I have never heard of one untwisting from normal use.

Comment: Isn't twist angle pretty well set when the blade is cast / manufactured? Wouldn't it get destroyed along the way to changing that angle while in service?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to grasp the subject.

Imagine that with accumulated flight hours, the blades of (for example) the power turbine get asymmetrically eroded, resulting in a change in the effective "twist angle" of the blade and a reduction in its efficiency.

For this to result in, say, a 10% reduction in the power generated by the turbine disc would necessarily involve a significant *thinning* of the blades themselves, rendering them unserviceable and requiring their replacement.

This means that the blades would not get reworked to correct the twist angle at that point, because they would be beyond their thickness wear limits.